# Can not find out how to use NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I am a newbie in cocoa . I really can't understand how to use NSTableView. Searched for a good example but couldn't find. Can anyone help me?

Google search resulted in  some huge coding. but I think there must be some easier way
in Cocoa.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for NSTableView, it lists five sample projects that you can download to see how it works.  If none of those make sense to you, then you may need to be more specific about what it is you're looking for.

Comment: The documentation is very well-written on this subject. **What have you tried** and **what went wrong**?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

check this short but useful video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dO02yQUH80

Comment: Links as answers are discouraged. -1.

Answer (score 1):

"Huge coding" is relative. You won't be able to implement a table with just a couple of lines of code. Implementing the data source and delegate methods of the table view will take at least 100 lines if not more. See [Populating View-Based Table Views Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH14-SW1).

An alternative might be using [Cocoa Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/cocoabindings/cocoabindings.html) to bind the content of your table view to an [`NSArrayController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).